# Funciones llamando a funciones

Tags: python-3.x, funciones

Estoy codificando desde Codecademy y me surge una duda bien básica sobre las "funciones llamando a otras funciones".

- ¿Cómo sabe Python qué argumentos tiene que usar para calcular el promedio?
- ¿Cuándo se definió?
- Es decir, en la función 3 veces se refiere a `numbers`, ¿significa que toma todos los números que encuentra?

Gracias

```
lloyd = {
  "name": "Lloyd",
  "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
  "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
  "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}

alice = {
  "name": "Alice",
  "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
  "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
  "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}

tyler = {
  "name": "Tyler",
  "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
  "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
  "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}
```

---

```
def average(numbers):
  total = sum(numbers)
  total = float(total)
  return total / len(numbers)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

se crea una función

```
def average(numbers): # declaración de la función
    total = sum(numbers) # se suman todos los números dentro de la lista
    total = float(total) # se transforma el int en float
    return total / len(numbers) # se retorna el resultado de la división entre el total de números que estaban en la lista números y la suma de ellos
```

luego se crea una lista con n cantidad de números para poder explicar la función

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

se llama a la función y se le da la lista como argumento

```
print(average(numbers))
```

con el diccionario no se que hacer ya que falta el código.

en realidad numbers es la variable que contiene la lista no es para llamar la función.para llamar la función se debe hacer como esta en el print. por favor escríbeme en los comentarios si tenes alguna inquietud

Comment: Hola Agustín, gracias. El diccionario viene así tal cual en el ejercicio. Y según el ejercicio numbers promedia los valores del diccionario. Mi pregunta concreta es, sin en vez de numbers pongo "gallinas" o cualquier palabra como argumento Python entiende que son los números del diccionario que tiene que tomar? Gracias

Comment: @Beaperel genial. Entonces con mí código lo único que tenés que hacer es crear un for que intere en los diccionarios y la lista dentro del diccionario lo envíe como argumento a la función

Comment: @Beaperel si necesitas ayuda no dudes en escribir. Actualizo el código para que pueda trabajar directamente con esos diccionarios

Answer (score 1):

> Cómo sabe Python qué argumentos tiene que usar para calcular el promedio?

Lo que se define con la declaración de la función, en este caso `numbers`. La variable `total` se define dentro de la función. Tanto `numbers` (el argumento de la función) y `total` (la variable que se define en la función) van a ser tomados en cuenta en el scope de la función.

> Es decir, en la función 3 veces se refiere a "numbers".

En cualquiera de los casos que se usa `numbers`, se usa como una expresión. A diferencia de `total`, que se usa como declaración.

```
total = sum(numbers)
```

Aquí se le asigna a `total` el resultado de la expresión `sum(numbers)`. Se dice que es una expresión debido a que su único propósito es ser evaluada, no tiene tiempo de vida. Esa linea de código es una declaración, a pesar que se use el resultado de una expresión.

```
total = float(total)
```

Esta otra linea es una declaración también, es una resignación a `total`. De cualquier manera `float(total)` es una expresión. Si bien se asigna el valor que retorna a `total`, una vez evaluada el elemento que persiste es `total` y no la expresión.

```
return total / len(numbers)
```

Esta linea es el retorno de la función, esto significa el final. Como dije `numbers` al ser un argumento de la función es tomada en cuenta en el scope de la función. Sin embargo, su tiempo de vida se limita a las evaluaciones que se hacen con esta. Nuevamente, `len(numbers)` por si sola es una expresión y `total / len(numbers)` también, por lo tanto **se está evaluando el resultado de una evaluación.**

Si te das cuenta esta función también es una expresión, el resultado de su evaluación es el valor que retorna. Después de haber sido definido el valor que retorne su invocación con su argumento se puede asignar a una variable o formar parte de otra expresiones. En si, no es más que una simple función, se evalúa para retornar un valor.

> significa que toma todos los números que encuentra?

`numbers` no es más que un argumento, se usa como argumento con el fin de que se tome en cuenta en el scope de la función, La función solo toma a `numbers`, depende de que se use como argumento. En este caso en específico se le tiene que pasar un iterable. Esto por que en todos los usos que se le da a `numbers` se requiere de uno.

Según [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

> Sums start and the items of an **iterable** from left to right and returns the total.

Según [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len):

> The argument may be a **sequence** (such as a string, bytes, tuple, list, or range) or a collection (such as a dictionary, set, or frozen set).

En caso de que no se use un argumento que también se pueda usar como argumento de `sum()` y `len()`, la función terminará en un error.

### Funciones llamando a otras funciones

Esto es posible a la posibilidad de retornar un valor, cuando se hacen asignaciones

```
variable = funcion(argumento)
```

Se le está asignando el valor que retorna `funcion()` a `variable`. Se le asigna el resultado de una evaluación. Si `funcion()` no retorna nada, `variable` tendrá el valor de `None`. La inclusión de `argumento` como argumento es con el fin de que sea cual sea el valor argumento, la función lo tome en cuenta (mientras no ocurra una excepción durante la ejecución).

Esto es comprobable de una manera muy fácil

```
def mult2(a):
    b = 2
    return a * b

print(4 == mult2(2))
```

La función `mult2()` multiplica el valor que se use como argumento por 2 (`b`). Para realizar la comparación que se hace, hay que evaluar a `mult2(2)`. Esta evaluación da como resultado a 2. Por lo tanto, es igual que decir

```
2 == 2
```

Esta evaluación terminará siendo

```
True
```